# How can I find the job jar from a hadoop job on the localFS?

Tags: java, hadoop

Using `JobConf.getJar()` gave me:

```
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/vagrant/.staging/job_1440651592962_0002/job.jar
```

Which turns out to be a HDFS path from `mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir`.

Using `find` I discovered it was actually stored in the appcache:

```
/vagrant/target/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/vagrant/appcache/
  application_1440651592962_0002/container_1440651592962_0002_01_000001/job.jar
  application_1440651592962_0002/filecache/10/job.jar
  application_1440651592962_0002/filecache/10/job.jar/job.jar
```

Which is based from `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs`

Is there any API sequence that can get me to the jar on normal disk?